# Get date value from spreadsheet using Google apps script

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been struggling to get proper "date" from spreadsheet using google apps script.
So below is scenario:
1. Google form submits request in Spreadsheet which has date column.
   so if request is submitted, spreadsheet saves date in local time zone.
   e.g. I have date "20/05/2019 09:00:00" which is already in local time zone(GMT+9:00).

2. Now, I read this value from google apps script using
   `var startTime = sheetObj.getRange(38, 6).getValue()`. This returns date object which adds 9 hours to time again. so I get date value as 
   "Mon May 20 18:00:00 GMT+09:00 2019". since my date is already in local time zone, I don't want to apply time timezone again. My expected output is "Mon May 20 9:00:00 GMT+09:00 2019" with date object.

But when I use `getDisplayedValues`, I get exact stored value but I need date as date object to create event in calendar with this date.

Am I missing something here?
My time zone of calendar, spreadsheet and Script are same- GMT+09:00.

Comment: Can't reproduce.  Please try to reproduce your issue on a new sheet, new script and a manually entered date/time.

Comment: Thanks.. I solved it. There was problem in spreadsheet setting. The locale was set to UK and timezone was set to GMT+9. Now I set locale setting to Japan. Now issue is not occuring.